# How to list fields from dynamic SQL query in SSRS dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm running the following query in SSRS. If I add declarations for the two parameters, it runs fine in SQL Management Console.

```
declare @EMRQuery varchar(max)
declare @CPSQuery varchar(max)

set @EMRQuery = 'select Person.ExternalId 
                    from ml.Person 
                        join ml.Obs on Person.pId = Obs.pId 
                            join ml.ObsHead on Obs.hdId = ObsHead.hdId 
                    where ObsHead.name = ''SCHOOLREGDTE'' 
                        and Obs.xId = 1.e+035
                        and Obs.change = 2 
                        and Obs.obsDate >= to_date(''' 
                            + convert(varchar(30), @DateYearStart, 120) 
                            + ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')
                        and Obs.obsDate < to_date(''' 
                            + convert(varchar(30), @DateQuarterEnd, 120) 
                            + ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')'

set @CPSQuery = 'select ic.ListName, count(distinct pp.patientprofileid) as PatCount
                    from PatientProfile pp
                        left join PatientInsurance pi on pp.PatientProfileId = pi.PatientProfileId
                                and pi.OrderForClaims = 1
                                and pi.Inactive <> 1
                            left join InsuranceCarriers ic on pi.InsuranceCarriersId = ic.InsuranceCarriersId
                        join OpenQuery(EMR_LIVE
                            ,  ''' + replace(@EMRQuery, '''', '''''') +
                        ''' ) Students on pp.PatientId = Students.ExternalId
                    group by ic.ListName '

exec(@CPSQuery)
```

However, when I plug this in to SSRS, it doesn't register that there are any fields available to report on. How do I convince SSRS that I do have fields to work with? Thanks.

Edit: I just declared the parameters in the query, and it recognized the field names.

```
declare @DateYearStart datetime
declare @DateQuarterEnd datetime
set @DateYearStart = '2011-07-01'
set @DateQuarterEnd = '2012-03-31'
```

Of course, that errored because I was declaring the parameters twice, once as query parameters and once within the query. But, as soon as I commented out the lines above, I lost the fields again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone over at the MSDN forums suggested I select into a temp table, so I replaced the final exec statement with

```
declare @CarrierList table (Listname varchar(200), PatCount int);
insert @CarrierList exec(@CPSQuery)
select * from @CarrierList
```

and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

How do you convince SSRS that you have fields to work with?  Answer:  Manually add the fields to the dataset from Dataset Properties...Fields.  This will make the designer happy and as long as the fields exist when the query is executed the report will work.  At least it worked for me using an OLE DB query to DB2 with dynamic query text.

Answer (score 1):

there is probably something wrong with your query. SSRS datasets can pretty much evaluate anything you put into them. FOr example, I just ran a little test with these 2 queries:

```
declare @a varchar(500)
declare @b varchar(500)
set @a = '(select name from sys.tables) B'
set @b = 'select B.name as name2 from '+@a
exec(@b)
```

and my datase set did recognize the field name2.

I advise you to review your query.

If it really doesnt work, you can try to add your code to a SQL Server procedure that returns a table with pre-defined fields names.

Comment: As I said, when I declared the parameters and supplied values for them, the query worked fine. It was when I passed the parameters into the dataset from the report that it wouldn't see the fields. But, when I added calculated fields to the dataset, I could see that it was returning the correct number of records, although I couldn't convince it to show me the fields I wanted to see.

Comment: I see now. Yes, it really doesn't generate the fields. Did you try the stored procedure idea?

Comment: Not yet. I may well have to go with that for a solution, but this report is going against a third-party application, and I try to mess with the data definitions as little as possible. (Learned that lesson when an Oracle materialized view I had built went out of control and started rebuilding itself every time the data was updated, instead of at 2:00 am every night...)

Answer (score 1):

Since SSRS executes the stored procedure with `SET FMTONLY ON;` when you click the refresh button. Then place a `SET FMTONLY OFF;` as the first line in your stored procedure and it will return your fields.

Comment: FMTONLY has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is because your code has two queries in it, even though only one is to be executed. I therefore suggest combining the two queries into a single query.

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately -- you'll notice that the first query is getting parameters, and OPEN_QUERY doesn't allow parameters. Expanding out the whole thing is the only way to do it.

Comment: @SarekOfVulcan: I can see why you would need to use dynamic SQL rather than binding the parameter values directly to the query. However, you should be able to declare the entire query (including the joined subquery in the OpenQuery) in a single SET statement. (Of course, this may not resolve the problem anyway!)

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I suspect it wouldn't help, but I'll try it later.

Comment: Didn't work. Still get the right number of records returned, but can't see the fields.